# php checkboxes send to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have php checkboxes and wanted to send its values in mysql using submit button if the checkboxes are check.

```
 while($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($gresult)) {
    $gsymbol = $grow['symbol'];
    $gclose = $grow['value'];
    echo "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>".$gsymbol."</td><td>".$gclose.</td<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'markings' value = '".$gsymbol."'></td></tr>"};
```

my question is do I have to echo a form or is there are more easier way. Thanks

Comment: You haven't closed your quotes properly, definitely want to check on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. @cosmoonot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would prefer to put PHP code inside your HTML. This is ugly, but I think it's better than echo the HTML.

It could be something like this:

```
<table>
<?php
while($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($gresult)):
    $gsymbol = $grow['symbol'];
    $gclose = $grow['value'];
?>
<tr>
    <td style='width: 100px;'><?php echo $gsymbol; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $gclose; ?></td>
    <td><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'markings' value = "<?php echo $gsymbol; ?>" ></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```